# Oracle - I want to find out delta changes in a database table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

The table is loaded every night with some data (around 100K rows). Then my batch job reads each record from the table and processes it. 
My requirement is to only process those records who have changes into specific columns because there is no point in processing a new record if it does not have any changes compared to yesterday's record (and it unnecessary delays whole processing of the job).

Please assume below table structure

Table Name: 
`STAGING_T`

Column Names:
`PK_1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | CREATE_DATE | FLAG`

CREATE_DATE is the sysdate when the data is loaded into this table. This is used to identify day wise data loaded into this table.

1. If a row is present in today's data but not in yesterday's(previous day's), update FLAG to 'INSERT'
2. If a row is present in yesterday's data but not in today's, update the FLAG to 'DELETE'
3. If a row is present in both today's and yesterday's data **and there is any change in COL3 and COL4 of both the records**, update the FLAG to 'UPDATE'.
4. If a row is present in both today's and yesterday's data **and there is NO change in COL3 and COL4 of both the records**, update the FLAG to 'NO CHANGE'.

Common columns based on which I identify the same records of yesterday and today are COL1 and COL2.

```
**Sample Data**
PK_1    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    CREATE_DATE FLAG
1       1000    2000    a       x       31.01.2019  
2       1000    2001    b       y       31.01.2019  
3       1000    2002    c       z       31.01.2019  
4       1000    2000    aa      x       30.01.2019  
5       1000    2001    b       y       30.01.2019  
6       1000    2003    d       z       30.01.2019  


**Expected Output**

PK_1    COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    CREATE_DATE FLAG
1       1000    2000    a       x       31.01.2019  UPDATE
2       1000    2001    b       y       31.01.2019  NO CHANGE
3       1000    2002    c       z       31.01.2019  INSERT
4       1000    2000    aa      x       30.01.2019  
5       1000    2001    b       y       30.01.2019  
6       1000    2003    d       z       30.01.2019
```

Any help or suggestions would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: What are the common columns based on which you identify the same records of yesterday and today? is it col1 and col2? sample data and expected output would help us to help you.

Comment: yes it is col1 and col2. I will also add the sample data and expected output.
Thanks :)

Comment: I have added sample data and expected output in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first generate the desired values and then use merge statement. You may try below -

```
MERGE INTO DATA T 
USING (SELECT D.PK_1, D.COL1, D.COL2, D.COL3, CREATE_DATE, D.COL4,
       CASE WHEN CREATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(CREATE_DATE) FROM DATA) THEN
            CASE WHEN LAG(COL3 || '`'||COL4) OVER(PARTITION BY COL1,COL2 ORDER BY CREATE_DATE) IS NULL
                      THEN 'INSERT'
                 WHEN LAG(COL3 || '`'||COL4) OVER(PARTITION BY COL1,COL2 ORDER BY CREATE_DATE)  = COL3 || '`'||COL4
                      THEN 'NO CHANGE'
                 ELSE 'UPDATE'
            END
       END FLAG
       FROM DATA D)
S ON (T.PK_1 = S.PK_1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.FLAG = S.FLAG;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1fdf76c7aa467446f021ef7f6daef00f) is the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MERGE` statement along with `aggregate functions` in the source part as follows:

```
MERGE INTO DATA T 
USING (
          SELECT COL1, COL2,
              MAX(CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) = CREATE_DATE THEN PK_1 END) TODAY_PK,
              MAX(CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 = CREATE_DATE  THEN PK_1 END) YEST_PK,
              COUNT(DISTINCT COL3) AS CNT_COL3,
              COUNT(DISTINCT COL4) AS CNT_COL4
          FROM DATA T
          WHERE CREATE_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
          GROUP BY COL1, COL2
      )
S ON ( T.COL1 = S.COL1
       AND T.COL2 = S.COL2
       AND T.CREATE_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE) )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.FLAG = CASE
    WHEN S.YEST_PK IS NULL THEN 'INSERT'
    WHEN S.TODAY_PK IS NULL THEN 'DELETE'
    WHEN S.CNT_COL3 > 1
         OR S.CNT_COL4 > 1 THEN 'UPDATE'
    ELSE 'NO CHANGE'
END;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3c6a5709830e21ed31ddbce94bce1ba)

I am assuming that your `CREATE_DATE` is a date with time as starting of the day, If not please use `TRUNC(CREATE_DATE)` instead of CREATE_DATE in the query.

Cheers!!

Comment: This is not generating the correct output - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca423e3d2a54e8ea50adb913c5052447

Comment: Ok, There was small mistake -1 should be on the left side in `MAX`. Updated the answer. Please check now!!

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this (not tested) :

```
   update STAGING_T  set FLAG = 'INSERT' where PK_1  in (
   select PK_1 from 
   STAGING_T T1
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate) --today
   and not exists (
   select 1  from  
   STAGING_T T2 
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate-1) --yesterday
          and T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 and T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 and T1.COL3 = T2.COL3 
          and T1.COL4 = T2.COL4
   )

)


   update STAGING_T  set FLAG = 'DELETE' where PK_1  in (
   select PK_1 from 
   STAGING_T T1
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate-1) --yesterday
   and not exists (
   select 1  from  
   STAGING_T T2 
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate) --today
          and T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 and T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 and T1.COL3 = T2.COL3 
          and T1.COL4 = T2.COL4
   )

)

   update STAGING_T  set FLAG = 'update' where PK_1  in (
   select PK_1 from 
   STAGING_T T1
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate-1) --yesterday
   and  exists (
   select 1  from  
   STAGING_T T2 
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate) --today
          and T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 and T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 and T1.COL3 <> T2.COL3 
          and T1.COL4 <> T2.COL4
   )

)


   update STAGING_T  set FLAG = 'no change' where PK_1  in (
   select PK_1 from 
   STAGING_T T1
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate-1) --yesterday
   and  exists (
   select 1  from  
   STAGING_T T2 
   where  trunc(CREATE_DATE)=trunc(sysdate) --today
          and T1.COL1 = T2.COL1 and T1.COL2 = T2.COL2 and T1.COL3 = T2.COL3 
          and T1.COL4 = T2.COL4
   )

)
```